# Computation of a finite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, gamma-function

I am working with Gamma functions and I needto compute the following sum:
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n   k\frac{\Gamma(n-k+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n-k+1)}=\sum_{k=1}^nk(n-k+\alpha)(n-k+\alpha-1)\cdots(n-k+1),
\end{align}
where $\alpha$ is an integer larger than $1$.

Is it possible in your opinion to compute an explicit expression of the previous sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all arguments are positive integers, we can use factorials. Our sum becomes
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-k+\alpha-1)!}{(n-k)!}k$$
Multiply by $\frac{(\alpha-1)!}{(\alpha-1)!}$ to get that our sum is equivalent to
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(n-k+\alpha-1)!}{(n-k)!(\alpha-1)!}k$$
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-k+\alpha-1}{\alpha-1}k$$
We can reverse the bounds of summation to get that our sum is equivalent to
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{k+\alpha-1}{\alpha-1}(n-k)$$
Note that $n-k=\sum_{j=k+1}^n 1$, so we can say our sum is equivalent to
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\binom{k+\alpha-1}{\alpha-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^n 1\right)$$
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=k+1}^n \binom{k+\alpha-1}{\alpha-1}$$
Now, we switch the order of summation to get
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=0}^{j-1} \binom{k+\alpha-1}{\alpha-1}$$
By hockey-stick identity, the inner sum is
$$(\alpha-1)!\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{j+\alpha-1}{\alpha}$$
Applying hockey-stick identity again, we get
$$(\alpha-1)!\binom{n+\alpha}{\alpha+1}$$

You can also use this identity from [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h2524641p21430298) to solve even more complex sums.

Comment: Since the question was for gamma functions, you could write this as $\dfrac{\Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}{\alpha(\alpha+1)\Gamma(n)}$ and thus extend it to non-integer $\alpha$

Comment: @Alan Thank you very match! It's wandeful your argument!

Comment: @Henry Thank you! I will think about that!

Comment: @Alan There is only one step that I don't understand well about your argument! It is when you switch the order of the summation: how do you understand that k varies between 0 ad j-1?. Thank you again!

Comment: Draw a diagram indicating all ordered pairs that are summed by $(k,j)$. It's kind of hard to explain, but if you write out all the points being summed for a smaller $n$ and then reorder it might make more sense.

Comment: Ok! I unserstood! Thank you again!